# R strptime convert int in character not list

Tags: r, strftime

I need to read a `.csv` file where its first column is time. Then, my idea is read this column (`typeof = int`) and transform to an R time class. Because I'm new in R, I first try with an example:

```
> myData2 <- data.frame(time=c("2014-01-23 14:28:21","2014-01-23 14:28:55",
                        "2014-01-23 14:29:02","2014-01-23 14:31:18"),
                 speed=c(2.0,2.2,3.4,5.5))

> myData2$time2 <- strptime(myData2$time,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
> typeof(myData2$time2[1])
[1] "list"
```

And works ok. But when I try with my real data, it doesn't.

```
> dt <- read.csv(my_data_path, header = TRUE)
> dt$new_time <- strftime(dt$Fecha, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
> typeof(dt$new_time[1])
[1] "character"
```

This are the first lines of my data:

```
Fecha,VelViento
1-1-2014 0:0,3.9364293533672887
1-1-2014 0:10,0.4790769693315504
1-1-2014 0:20,6.060318186583566
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: you are using `strptime` in the first example and `strftime` in the second

Comment: `strptime` returns a POSIXlt object which is a list. If you had done the initial conversion with `as.POSIXct`, which returns a numeric vector with POSIXct and POSIXt attributes, you might have been happier.